# Implementing DataType abstraction in Haskell

Tags: haskell, abstraction, abstract-data-type

I want to implement am Abstract Datype in haskell.
Given a moule with a defined type, say Mytype:

```
module A (myType,MyType) where

type MyType = Float

mytype :: Float -> MyType
myType f = f
```

Implemented internally as a single Float, I exported only a function to construct a value given a Float, and the type itself.
The problem is, when I load that module, I can acces the implementation.

Given:

```
module B where
import A

data OtherType = One MyType
               | Two MyType MyType
               deriving Show
```

I can construct an object of type OtherType like this:

```
One $ mytype 1.0
```

Or like this:

```
One $ (1.0 :: Float)
```

With a real abstraction I shouldn't be able to do that!

How can I export the type Mytype, in a way such that I can only construct values from my constructor functions

Comment: `type` doesn't create anything new. It just creates a convenient name for an already existing type. Once the code is compiled, your type synonyms are gone, and `mytype` will have type `Float -> Float`

Comment: `type` behaves equivalent to `typedef` in C if you're familiar with that. You're looking for `data` or `newtype`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an Algebraic Datatype instead:

```
module A (myType,MyType) where

data MyType = MyType Float

mytype :: Float -> MyType
myType f = MyType f
```

Then, trying to evaluate things like

```
One (MyType 3.0)
```

throws  "Not in scope: data constructor `MyType'"

Comment: Or `newtype`.  The key point is to not use `type`, because that's not what it does.